# Regular expression to return string split up respecting nested parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I know many answers exist to the question on how to split up a string respecting parenthesis, but they never do so recursively.
Looking at the string `1 2 3 (test 0, test 0) (test (0 test) 0)`:
Regex `\s(?![^\(]*\))` returns `"1", "2", "3", "(test 0, test 0)", "(test", "(0 test) 0)"`
The regex I'm looking for would return either
`"1", "2", "3", "(test 0, test 0)", "(test (0 test)0)"`
or
`"1", "2", "3", "test 0, test 0", "test (0 test)0"`
which would let me recursively use it on the results again until no parentheses remain.
Ideally it would also respect escaped parentheses, but I myself am not this advanced in regex knowing only the basics.
Does anyone have an idea on how to take on this?

Comment: What makes you think `regex` is the right tool for this problem?

Comment: When components of your string have semantic value, such as balanced parenthesis, you're better off tokenizing and parsing. Regular expressions can be a component of your lexer/tokenizer, but aren't optimal for doing the entire job.

Comment: Often it helps to choose a sustainable solution, when we know the context/background: Where do these string expressions formed of numbers and parentheses originate from? What do they represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `regex` only for the task might work but it wouldn't be straightforward.

Another possibility is writing a simple algorithm to track the parentheses in the string:

1. Split the string at all parentheses, while returning the delimiter (e.g. using `re.split`)
2. Keep a counters tracking the parentheses: `start_parens_count` for `(` and `end_parens_count` for `)`.
3. Using the counters, proceed by either splitting at white spaces or adding the current data into a temp var ( `term`)
4. When the left most parenthesis has been closed, append `term` to the list of values & reset the counters/temp vars.

Here's an example:

```
import re

string = "1 2 3 (test 0, test 0) (test (0 test) 0)"


result, start_parens_count, end_parens_count, term = [], 0, 0, ""
for x in re.split(r"([()])", string):
    if not x.strip():
        continue
    elif x == "(":
        if start_parens_count > 0:
            term += "("
        start_parens_count += 1
    elif x == ")":
        end_parens_count += 1
        if end_parens_count == start_parens_count:
            result.append(term)
            end_parens_count, start_parens_count, term = 0, 0, ""
        else:
            term += ")"
    elif start_parens_count > end_parens_count:
        term += x
    else:
        result.extend(x.strip(" ").split(" "))


print(result)
# ['1', '2', '3', 'test 0, test 0', 'test (0 test) 0']
```

Not very elegant, but works.

Comment: The parsing algorithm is a solid approach and well explained together with expressive code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip install regex` and use

```
import regex
text = "1 2 3 (test 0, test 0) (test (0 test) 0)"
matches = [match.group() for match in regex.finditer(r"(?:(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))|\S)+", text)]
print(matches)
# => ['1', '2', '3', '(test 0, test 0)', '(test (0 test) 0)']
```

See the [online Python demo](https://tio.run/##LY3BCoMwEETvfsWS024tovVWqPmIHtVCaaPmYBLWLVjw31OrnmZ4MPPCVwbvyhjtGDwLsOnNnIiZBW6gCrhACShmEsjPsCcdAPMN0EpUMj7lNZhpHdVbzXr2n4AEnWfYCFi3v2eddW8rhpEV6is2iLqqH0htuqAuiE4N0dLcKVV/5SzUJoGtEzwkFOMP). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mWH8jh/1).
The regex matches:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))` - a text between any nested parentheses
- `|` - or

  - `\S` - any non-whitespace char
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat one or more times

Comment: Did you mean the last quantifier to be inside the non-capturing group?

Comment: @oriberu No, but what you suggest would look like `(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))|\S+`.

Comment: I was wondering, because quantifying the whole expression should not change your result, while quantifying the non-whitespace group allows it to match more than one character (presuming non-parenthesized sequences could be more than one character long, even if that wasn't in the test data).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) as well.

```py
import pyparsing as pp

pattern = pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Regex(r'\S+') ^ pp.original_text_for(pp.nested_expr('(', ')')))

# Tests
string = '1 2 3 (test 0, test 0) (test (0 test) 0)'
result = pattern.parse_string(string).as_list()
answer = ['1', '2', '3', '(test 0, test 0)', '(test (0 test) 0)']
assert result == answer

string = ''
result = pattern.parse_string(string).as_list()
answer = []
assert result == answer

string = 'a'
result = pattern.parse_string(string).as_list()
answer = ['a']
assert result == answer

string = ' a (1) ! '
result = pattern.parse_string(string).as_list()
answer = ['a', '(1)', '!']
assert result == answer

string = ' a (b) cd (e f) g hi (j (k l) m) (o p (qr (s t) u v) w (x y) z)'
result = pattern.parse_string(string).as_list()
answer = ['a', '(b)', 'cd', '(e f)', 'g', 'hi', '(j (k l) m)', '(o p (qr (s t) u v) w (x y) z)']
assert result == answer
```

* `pyparsing` can be installed by `pip install pyparsing`

In addition, you can directly parse all the nested parentheses at once:

```py
pattern = pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Regex(r'\S+') ^ pp.nested_expr('(', ')'))

string = '1 2 3 (test 0, test 0) (test (0 test) 0)'
result = pattern.parse_string(string).as_list()
answer = ['1', '2', '3', ['test', '0,', 'test', '0'], ['test', ['0', 'test'], '0']]
assert result == answer
```

* Whitespace is a delimiter in this case.

##### Note:

If a pair of parentheses gets broken inside `()` (for example `a(b(c)`, `a(b)c)`, etc), an unexpected result is obtained or `IndexError` is raised. So be careful to use. (See: [Python extract string in a phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70953916/python-extract-string-in-a-phrase/70959340#70959340))