# Python extract string in a phrase

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a python string that comes in a standard format string and i want to extract a piece of that string.

The string come as such:

```
logs(env:production service:FourDS3.Expirer @Properties.NewStatus:(ChallengeAbandoned OR Expired) @Properties.Source:Session).index(processing).rollup(count).by(@Properties.AcsInfo.Host).last(15m) > 60
```

I want to extract everything between `logs()`, that is i need to get this `env:production service:FourDS3.Expirer @Properties.NewStatus:(ChallengeAbandoned OR Expired) @Properties.Source:Session`

I have tried the below regex but it's not working:

```
result = re.search('logs((.+?)).', message.strip())
return result.group(1)

result = re.search('logs((.*?)).', message.strip())
return result.group(1)
```

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Conclusion first:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

txt = 'logs(env:production service:FourDS3.Expirer @Properties.NewStatus:(ChallengeAbandoned OR Expired) @Properties.Source:Session).index(processing).rollup(count).by(@Properties.AcsInfo.Host).last(15m) > 60'

pattern = pp.Regex(r'.*?logs(?=\()') + pp.original_text_for(pp.nested_expr('(', ')'))
result = pattern.parse_string(txt)[1][1:-1]
print(result)
```

* You can install `pyparsing` by `pip install pyparsing`

If you persist in using regex, my answer would not be appropriate.
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454510/18059879), however, it seems difficult to parse such nested parentheses by regex. So, I used [pyparsing](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to deal with your case.

#### Other examples:

The following examples work fine as well:

```py
txt = 'logs(a(bc)d)e'
result = pattern.parse_string(txt)[1][1:-1]
print(result) # a(bc)d

txt = 'logs(a(b(c)d)e(f)g)h(ij(k)l)m'
result = pattern.parse_string(txt)[1][1:-1]
print(result) # a(b(c)d)e(f)g
```

#### Note:

Unfortunately, if a pair of parentheses gets broken inside `logs()`, an unexpected result is obtained or `IndexError` is raised. So you have to be careful about what kind of text comes in:

```py
txt = 'logs(a)b)c'
result = pattern.parse_string(txt)[1][1:-1]
print(result) # a

txt = 'logs(a(b)c'
result = pattern.parse_string(txt)[1][1:-1]
print(result) # IndexError
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will review each one of them carefully and let you know :)

Comment: You're welcome. I made a small update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that input string is always in exactly the same format, then you could use the fact that the closing bracket for `logs` is followed by a `.`:

```py
original = '''logs(env:production service:FourDS3.Expirer @Properties.NewStatus:(ChallengeAbandoned OR Expired)@Properties.Source:Session).index(processing).rollup(count).by(@Properties.AcsInfo.Host).last(15m) > 60'''
extracted = original.split('logs(')[1].split(').')[0]
print(extracted)
```

Which gives you this, without the need for regex:

```py
'env:production service:FourDS3.Expirer @Properties.NewStatus:(ChallengeAbandoned OR Expired)@Properties.Source:Session'
```

Comment: Seems like a fair way to do it but any chance we could achieve this through regex ? 
Just asking

Comment: this assumes that after `logs()` there's a `.` which although matches the example is not what the question asks: `I want to extract everything between logs()`

Comment: That's a fair point, @SembeiNorimaki, hence the caveat at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result via regex like this:

```
input = "logs(env:production service:FourDS3.Expirer @Properties.NewStatus:(ChallengeAbandoned OR Expired) @Properties.Source:Session).index(processing).rollup(count).by(@Properties.AcsInfo.Host).last(15m) > 60"
pattern = r'logs\((?P<log>.*)\).index'
print(re.search(pattern, input).group('log'))
# which prints:
# env:production service:FourDS3.Expirer @Properties.NewStatus:(ChallengeAbandoned OR Expired) @Properties.Source:Session
```

The `?<P>` is a [named group](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups), which you access by calling `group` with the name specified inside `<>`

Comment: This assumes that `.index` always follows `logs()` like `logs(...somehting here...).index`

Comment: Yes, this won't work if `.index` is not provided in the query or is in another position in the query